# Eclipse: add JPanel in JFrame

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I wrote a simple project about Swing (without action listener).
I want to add a button to a `JPanel` and add the panel (named `panel`) to a `JFrame` (named `frame`). But when I added the panel to the frame, Eclipse had an error:

```
The type javax.swing.JComponent cannot be resolved. It is 
    indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

This is my source:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Click {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("oooooo");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    frame.add(panel); //the error
    }
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: This (seems) to be a common issue with Eclipse - just do a search for [eclipse javax.swing.JComponent cannot be resolved](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=eclipse+javax.swing.JComponent+cannot+be+resolved&oq=eclipse+javax.swing.JComponent+cannot+be+resolved&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2627j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and you'll find a number of other people who have also had simular issues

Comment: So Should I change my compiler?

Comment: Have read through some of the other question/answers, try a few things, if you're still having problems, post a question listing all the things you've tried

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is an issue with JRE your eclipse is running on and jre build path is pointing.
I suggest you to follow steps:

1. Right click on your project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path
2. Go to 'Libraries' tab
3. Remove Previous Version
4. Add Library -> JRE System Library -> Next -> Workspace default JRE
   (or you can Choose Alternate JRE from your System) -> Finish